# Asp.net Url rewriting for variable number of querystring arguments

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

i need to route an url like this

```
routes.MapPageRoute("id", "Destinations/{param1}_{param2}_{param3}", "~/RealPage.aspx");
```

The problem is that number of query string parameters may vary:

```
http://url/Destinations/us_us_us
http://url/Destinations/__us
http://url/Destinations/us__
http://url/Destinations/___
```

Comment: What would like to get as result ?

Comment: there is a web page with 3 inputs, then with javascript i redirect to the routed url  location.href(....+document.getelementbyid.value...) so if an input box is empty the route cannot be faund. so i need a way to route param1_param2_param3 or _ _ param3 or param1_ _  and so on

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I can say what may be not the best way, but you need parse the result manually try to use RegEx for this operation.